# OPENXML import xml to ms sql - namespace

Tags: sql, xml, namespaces, xquery, sql-server-openxml

I used this site for a long time, and many times it helped me in solving various problems.
This time i'm stuck. I try to import a complex xml like the one bellow into ms-sql table.

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S2SCTScf:SCTScfBlkCredTrf xmlns="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf" xmlns:S2SCTScf="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf SCTScfBlkCredTrf.xsd">
  <S2SCTScf:SndgInst>XXXXXXXX</S2SCTScf:SndgInst>
  <S2SCTScf:RcvgInst>YYYYYYYY</S2SCTScf:RcvgInst>
  <S2SCTScf:SrvcId>SCT</S2SCTScf:SrvcId>
  <S2SCTScf:TstCode>P</S2SCTScf:TstCode>
  <S2SCTScf:FType>SCF</S2SCTScf:FType>
  <S2SCTScf:FileRef>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</S2SCTScf:FileRef>
  <S2SCTScf:RoutingInd>IND</S2SCTScf:RoutingInd>
  <S2SCTScf:FileBusDt>2016-11-01</S2SCTScf:FileBusDt>
  <S2SCTScf:FileCycleNo>01</S2SCTScf:FileCycleNo>
  <S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02">
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgId>111111111111111111</MsgId>
      <CreDtTm>2016-11-01T15:45:11.0Z</CreDtTm>
      <NbOfTxs>11</NbOfTxs>
      <TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">111111</TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt>
      <IntrBkSttlmDt>2016-11-01</IntrBkSttlmDt>
      <SttlmInf>
        <SttlmMtd>CLRG</SttlmMtd>
        <ClrSys>
          <Prtry>ST2</Prtry>
        </ClrSys>
      </SttlmInf>
      <InstgAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>XXXXXXXX</BIC>
        </FinInstnId>
      </InstgAgt>
      <InstdAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>XXXXXXXX</BIC>
        </FinInstnId>
      </InstdAgt>
    </GrpHdr>
    <CdtTrfTxInf>
      <PmtId>
        <EndToEndId>NOTPROVIDED</EndToEndId>
        <TxId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</TxId>
      </PmtId>
      <PmtTpInf>
        <SvcLvl>
          <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
        </SvcLvl>
      </PmtTpInf>
      <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="XXX">1.00</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
      <ChrgBr>SLEV</ChrgBr>
      <Dbtr>
        <Nm>MXXXXXX XXXXXXX</Nm>
        <PstlAdr>
          <Ctry>XX</Ctry>
          <AdrLine>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</AdrLine>
        </PstlAdr>
      </Dbtr>
      <DbtrAcct>
        <Id>
          <IBAN>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</IBAN>
        </Id>
      </DbtrAcct>
      <DbtrAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>XXXXXXXXXXX</BIC>
        </FinInstnId>
      </DbtrAgt>
      <CdtrAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>XXXXXXXXXX</BIC>
        </FinInstnId>
      </CdtrAgt>
      <Cdtr>
        <Nm>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Nm>
      </Cdtr>
      <CdtrAcct>
        <Id>
          <IBAN>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</IBAN>
        </Id>
      </CdtrAcct>
      <RmtInf>
        <Ustrd>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Ustrd>
      </RmtInf>
    </CdtTrfTxInf>
    <CdtTrfTxInf>
      <PmtId>
        <EndToEndId>NOTPROVIDED</EndToEndId>
        <TxId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</TxId>
      </PmtId>
      <PmtTpInf>
        <SvcLvl>
          <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
        </SvcLvl>
      </PmtTpInf>
      <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="XXX">1.00</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
      <ChrgBr>SLEV</ChrgBr>
      <Dbtr>
        <Nm>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Nm>
        <PstlAdr>
          <Ctry>XX</Ctry>
          <AdrLine>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</AdrLine>
        </PstlAdr>
      </Dbtr>
      <DbtrAcct>
        <Id>
          <IBAN>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</IBAN>
        </Id>
      </DbtrAcct>
      <DbtrAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</BIC>
        </FinInstnId>
      </DbtrAgt>
      <CdtrAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</BIC>
        </FinInstnId>
      </CdtrAgt>
      <Cdtr>
        <Nm>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Nm>
      </Cdtr>
      <CdtrAcct>
        <Id>
          <IBAN>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</IBAN>
        </Id>
      </CdtrAcct>
      <RmtInf>
        <Ustrd>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Ustrd>
      </RmtInf>
    </CdtTrfTxInf>
  </S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
</S2SCTScf:SCTScfBlkCredTrf>
```

I try OPENXML and also XQuery functions but i'm having some issues on declaring and using the namespaces (or namespaceuri). I'm not familiar with such complex xml and namespaceuri. I need an ideea to get data bellow to a table. I have succeed using more simple xml, even with one namespace. I have manualy deleted the first 11 lines and the select bellow works very fine...

```html
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML where id=6 --this is the xml without first 11 lines
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML
SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/CdtTrfTxInf')
  WITH 
  (
    CCY [varchar](100) 'IntrBkSttlmAmt/@Ccy',
    IntrBkSttlmAmt [varchar](100) 'IntrBkSttlmAmt',
    TxId [varchar](100) 'PmtId/TxId',
    EndToEndId [varchar](100) 'PmtId/EndToEndId',
    ChrgBr [varchar](100) 'ChrgBr'
    --etc
  )
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks first

- `FROM OPENXML` is outdated and should not be used any more (rare exceptions exits)
- Your XML includes an explicit encoding here `<?xml version=''1.0'' encoding=''UTF-8''?>`. This forces you to go the `VARCHAR`-path, which is dangerous in connections with not plain latin characters. Better replace this with `utf-16` and go the `NVARCHAR`-path. In this case you **must** set a "N" in front of your XML literal.
- You have to deal with quite complex namespaces... hard to read... If you can be sure, that there are no names repeated, you might let the namespace declaration away and place a `*:` in front of each element.
- What adds some extra effort: Your inner `S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf` defines a new default namespace. I aliased this with `innerDeflt`.

This is the variables declaration

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<?xml version=''1.0'' encoding=''UTF-8''?>
<S2SCTScf:SCTScfBlkCredTrf xmlns="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf" xmlns:S2SCTScf="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf SCTScfBlkCredTrf.xsd">
  <S2SCTScf:SndgInst>XXXXXXXX</S2SCTScf:SndgInst>
  <S2SCTScf:RcvgInst>YYYYYYYY</S2SCTScf:RcvgInst>
  <S2SCTScf:SrvcId>SCT</S2SCTScf:SrvcId>
  <S2SCTScf:TstCode>P</S2SCTScf:TstCode>
  <S2SCTScf:FType>SCF</S2SCTScf:FType>
  <S2SCTScf:FileRef>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</S2SCTScf:FileRef>
  <S2SCTScf:RoutingInd>IND</S2SCTScf:RoutingInd>
  <S2SCTScf:FileBusDt>2016-11-01</S2SCTScf:FileBusDt>
  <S2SCTScf:FileCycleNo>01</S2SCTScf:FileCycleNo>
  <S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02">
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgId>111111111111111111</MsgId>
      <CreDtTm>2016-11-01T15:45:11.0Z</CreDtTm>
      <NbOfTxs>11</NbOfTxs>
      <TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">111111</TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt>
      <IntrBkSttlmDt>2016-11-01</IntrBkSttlmDt>
      <SttlmInf>
        <SttlmMtd>CLRG</SttlmMtd>
        <ClrSys>
          <Prtry>ST2</Prtry>
        </ClrSys>
      </SttlmInf>
      <InstgAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>XXXXXXXX</BIC>
        </FinInstnId>
      </InstgAgt>
      <InstdAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>XXXXXXXX</BIC>
        </FinInstnId>
      </InstdAgt>
    </GrpHdr>
    <CdtTrfTxInf>
      <PmtId>
        <EndToEndId>NOTPROVIDED</EndToEndId>
        <TxId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</TxId>
      </PmtId>
      <PmtTpInf>
        <SvcLvl>
          <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
        </SvcLvl>
      </PmtTpInf>
      <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="XXX">1.00</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
      <ChrgBr>SLEV</ChrgBr>
      <Dbtr>
        <Nm>MXXXXXX XXXXXXX</Nm>
        <PstlAdr>
          <Ctry>XX</Ctry>
          <AdrLine>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</AdrLine>
        </PstlAdr>
      </Dbtr>
      <DbtrAcct>
        <Id>
          <IBAN>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</IBAN>
        </Id>
      </DbtrAcct>
      <DbtrAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>XXXXXXXXXXX</BIC>
        </FinInstnId>
      </DbtrAgt>
      <CdtrAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>XXXXXXXXXX</BIC>
        </FinInstnId>
      </CdtrAgt>
      <Cdtr>
        <Nm>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Nm>
      </Cdtr>
      <CdtrAcct>
        <Id>
          <IBAN>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</IBAN>
        </Id>
      </CdtrAcct>
      <RmtInf>
        <Ustrd>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Ustrd>
      </RmtInf>
    </CdtTrfTxInf>
    <CdtTrfTxInf>
      <PmtId>
        <EndToEndId>NOTPROVIDED</EndToEndId>
        <TxId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</TxId>
      </PmtId>
      <PmtTpInf>
        <SvcLvl>
          <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
        </SvcLvl>
      </PmtTpInf>
      <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="XXX">1.00</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
      <ChrgBr>SLEV</ChrgBr>
      <Dbtr>
        <Nm>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Nm>
        <PstlAdr>
          <Ctry>XX</Ctry>
          <AdrLine>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</AdrLine>
        </PstlAdr>
      </Dbtr>
      <DbtrAcct>
        <Id>
          <IBAN>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</IBAN>
        </Id>
      </DbtrAcct>
      <DbtrAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</BIC>
        </FinInstnId>
      </DbtrAgt>
      <CdtrAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</BIC>
        </FinInstnId>
      </CdtrAgt>
      <Cdtr>
        <Nm>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Nm>
      </Cdtr>
      <CdtrAcct>
        <Id>
          <IBAN>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</IBAN>
        </Id>
      </CdtrAcct>
      <RmtInf>
        <Ustrd>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Ustrd>
      </RmtInf>
    </CdtTrfTxInf>
  </S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
</S2SCTScf:SCTScfBlkCredTrf>';
```

And this is the query: First of all the namespaces are declared. Your nodes are pure structured 1:1, so one can read them simply by adding element name after element name forming the `XPath`. Only `<CdtTrfTxInf>` appears twice which needs a `1:n-approach` with `APPLY` and `.nodes()`.

In my example you get one template for any kind of data hidden in your XML. The rest is up to you.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT  'urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf'
                           ,'urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf' as S2SCTScf
                           ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi
                           ,'urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf SCTScfBlkCredTrf.xsd' AS schemaLocation
                           ,'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02' AS innerDeflt)
SELECT rt.value(N'(S2SCTScf:SndgInst)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS SndgInst
      ,rt.value(N'(S2SCTScf:RcvgInst)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS RcvgInst
      --more like this
      ,rt.value(N'(S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/innerDeflt:GrpHdr/innerDeflt:MsgId)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS MsgId
      ,rt.value(N'(S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/innerDeflt:GrpHdr/innerDeflt:CreDtTm)[1]','datetime') AS CreDtTm
      --more like this
      ,rt.value(N'(S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/innerDeflt:GrpHdr/innerDeflt:TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt/@Ccy)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt_Ccy
      ,rt.value(N'(S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/innerDeflt:GrpHdr/innerDeflt:TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt)[1]','int') AS TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt
      --all nodes are 1:1, just "more of the same"
      --But CdtTrfTxInf is there twice, therefore the call to OUTER APPLY rt.nodes()
      ,cti.value(N'(innerDeflt:PmtId/innerDeflt:EndToEndId)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS EndToEndId
      --all the rest is following the same schema...
FROM @xml.nodes(N'S2SCTScf:SCTScfBlkCredTrf') AS A(rt) --root
OUTER APPLY rt.nodes(N'S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/innerDeflt:CdtTrfTxInf') AS B(cti) --CdtTrfTxInf
```

The partial result (captions shifted...)

```
SndgInst    RcvgInst    MsgId               CreDtTm     TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt_Ccy   TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt   EndToEndId
XXXXXXXX    YYYYYYYY    111111111111111111  2016-11-01 15:45:11.000 EUR 111111  NOTPROVIDED
XXXXXXXX    YYYYYYYY    111111111111111111  2016-11-01 15:45:11.000 EUR 111111  NOTPROVIDED
```

Comment: Wow. this is awesome. Thank you thank you 1000 times :)) . I only change  for TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt from int to decimal and it works like a charm. I now continue to add all my fields in the select statement.